Issues with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission in .NET MAUI 8
I'm working on a .NET MAUI 8 application and I'm facing an issue with accessing external storage. I need to read files from external storage, but my attempts to request the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission are failing.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Requesting Permission: I have implemented the permission request logic for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but it is being denied immediately.
Permission Status Check: I checked the permission status and it's being reported as denied, even though other permissions work fine.
GitHub Solution: I followed a solution from this GitHub repository, but it didn't resolve the issue. (https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/PlatformIntegration/PlatformIntegrationDemos)
What I've done:
I have ensured that I added the necessary permission in the Android AndroidManifest.xml file.
I have handled permission requests and status checks according to the documentation.
Code snippets:
AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
Permission Request Code:

var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    // Handle the denied permission case
}


My environment:
.NET MAUI version: 8
Target Android version: 14
minimum Android version 5
Can someone help me figure out why the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is being denied in my .NET MAUI 8 app? Are there any additional steps or configurations required to successfully request and use this permission? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Please format your post so it’s readable.  Normal text should not be formatted as code blocks

also, are you really targeting Android 7?

Sorry actually Target android version is 14, and minimum android version is 5

For the target android 13, the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> has been removed, so the dialog about permission request will never appear on the android 13 or higher. The value of the Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead> will always be PermissionStatus.Denied.
But as a workaround, you can change your application's target android version to the android 12 to make the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission request alert still appear on the device with android 13 or higher. Add the following code in the AndroidManifest.xml:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

Note:
And there are some relative issues, you can follow up them here:
Permissions CheckStatusAsync Or CheckStatusAsync returns Denied instead of restricted
Permission bug: Bluetooth scanning without location permission on Android 12+

Hi thanks for the answer, my target android version is 14 and with .NET 8 i can't lower it.
and is there any way to get READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in android >= 13?
Why they have removed it, is there any way to get it?

Have you tried to add the code I shared above on file AndroidManifest.xml?

Hi, @JessieZhang-MSFT Thanks for the trick it worked as i got the pop-up and permission showed Granted but why it could not find the files in the directory!
check this below-
if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted)
{
string folderPath = "/storage/emulated/0/MIUI/sound_recorder/call_rec";
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
{                
}

}

This should be another problem. One problem, one thread. For this new problem, you can create a new thread. We are all willing to help you. :)

Thanks for the help. Yes I will create another one. Thank you again :-)
